# Laravel Spatie/Newsletter doesn't add contact in Mailchimp

Tags: laravel-5, newsletter, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am working on an integration between my laravel 5.2 app and MailChimp. I have downloaded and installed the spatie/newsletter https://github.com/spatie/laravel-newsletter  but form some reasons the integration doesn't work meaning a contact is not created in mailchimp. I have added the providers and aliases in the config/app.php file, config/larave-newsletter.php file contain the proper settings

```
    /*
     * The api key of a MailChimp account. You can find yours here:
     * https://us10.admin.mailchimp.com/account/api-key-popup/
     */
    'apiKey' => env('MAILCHIMP_APIKEY'),

    /*
     * When not specifying a listname in the various methods, use the list with this name
     */
    'defaultListName' => 'ListName',

    /*
     * Here you can define properties of the lists you want to
     * send campaigns.
     */
    'lists' => [

        /*
         * This key is used to identify this list. It can be used
         * in the various methods provided by this package.
         *
         * You can set it to any string you want and you can add
         * as many lists as you want.
         */
        'subscribers' => [

            /*
             * A mail chimp list id. Check the mailchimp docs if you don't know
             * how to get this value:
             * http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/managing-subscribers/find-your-list-id
             */
            'id' => env('MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID'),
        ],
    ],

    /*
     * If you're having trouble with https connections, set this to false.
     */
    'ssl' => true,
```

My controller contains the following:

```
Newsletter::subscribe($user->email, ['FNAME'=>$user->first_name, 'LNAME'=>$user->last_name]);
```

The strange thing is when I use tinker to add a contact, it does work

> Newsletter::subscribe($user->email, ["FNAME"=>$user->first_name, "LNAME"=>$u
>   ser->last_name]);

Is there a workaround for this issue and how can I solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix the issue by changing the default ssl setting from true to false. It appears my server was having some issues with https connections.
Should one experience a similar issue, they can try setting 'ssl'=>false in the config/laravel-newsletter.php file maybe it'll fix their issue.

Answer (score 0):

**I solved the same problem**

run this commandes :

- composer install
- php artisan config:cache
- php artisan route:cache

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by setting 'endpoint' to null instead of an empty string (as specified in the install instructions) in config/newsletter.php